# Javascript map arrays and merge to one object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a following firebase function

```
  this.sensorService.getTest()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(actions =>
        actions.map(a => ({
          [a.payload.key]: a.payload.val()
        })))
    ).subscribe(sensors => {
      this.sensors = sensors;
      console.log(this.sensors);
    });
```

It now returns data to different arrays and console.log shows following:

```
0: {groups: Array(8)}1: {links: Array(35)}2: {nodes: Array(35)}
```

How can I merge all these arrays together and have them all inside one object? Console.log should return:

```
{groups: Array(8), nodes: Array(35), links: Array(35)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `map` you could use `reduce` like that:

```
actions.reduce((acc, a) => {
  acc[a.payload.key] = a.payload.val();

  return acc;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
const values = {
   0: { groups: Array(8) },
   1: { links: Array(35) },
   2: { nodes: Array(35) }
};
```

You can retrieve values as an array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and the reduce the array to an object with [destructured assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
Object.values(values).reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, ...val }), {})
```

Comment: As much as I like the syntax, you're creating a new object for every loop here